# Импорт golang из python

Tags: python, c, golang

Мне требуется сделать импорт golang пакета в python коде. Я нашёл, что [обычно](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) это [делают](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/324250/) с помощью компиляции динамической c-библиотеки. Ровно также написано и в [документации](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go).

Моя утилита использует тип `struct`. На текущий момент, я не нашёл способа получить golang структуры в коде C. Возможно ли это Если нет, есть ли обходные пути для решения этой проблемы?

[github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38400)

Comment: Т.е. в документации сказано, что этого сделать нельзя, но вы всё равно спрашиваете, как это сделать? Думаете разработчики go что-то скрывают и  на самом деле есть тайная дверь, через которую можно всё что захочешь? Перепишите свою библиотеку на Си - и тогда её можно будет подключить как к python, так и к go (и ещё к десятку других языков).

Comment: @zed Я думаю, что это, по меньшей мере, странно. Учитывая, что golang довольно развитый язык, это, мягко говоря, серьёзный недостаток. Кроме того, как выяснил, можно использовать c-типы.

Comment: @zed Я же сюда прихожу не за тем, чтобы мне сказали: "парень, прочти ещё раз доку". Я сюда прихожу, чтобы понять, какие альтернативы, кроме стандартных.

Comment: У go много и более серьёзных недостатков, не смотря на его типа "развитость". А  использование Си-типов равносильно тому, чтобы переписать всё на Си. Только хуже.

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, что именно вызывает у вас проблемы.  Напишите (псевдо)кодом, что вы хотите сделать в *Python* или *Go,* что у вас сейчас не выходит, и какие возникают ошибки.

Comment: @Ainar-G я же вроде написал, что нельзя в C импортнуть гошные структуры